# Como utilizar código de PHP en Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tengo un formulario dinámico con el que guardo la información ingresada en los inputs en una base de datos. Mis inputs en html los tengo de esta manera:

```
 <input name="name[]" id="name"/>
```

Para agregar otro input tengo lo siguiente en el código de jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   var html= '<p /><input name="name[]" id="namechild"/>'
$("#add").click(function(e){
                    $("#container").append(html);
                });
});
```

Ahora, en otro input tengo el valor de la sesión, de esta manera

```
<input name="nsesion[]" id="nsesion" value="<?echo $nombresesion ?>" />
```

Cuando agrego ese input a la variable en jquery queda de esta manera

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   var html= '<p /><input name="name[]" id="namechild"/> <input name="nsesion[]" id="nsesionchild" value="<?php echo $nombresesion ?> />'
```

Pero al hacer esto mi código ya no funciona. No genera nuevos inputs ni guarda la información en la base de datos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para guardar el valor de esa variable en cada una de las filas insertadas en la base de datos?

Comment: ¿La página principal es php? ¿Ese código javascript está definido en un archivo .js a parte?

Answer (score 1):

En un documento **`.js`** no se puede meter código de **`PHP`**. Por lo que si tu vista HTML está en **`PHP`** te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script>
   // Guardar la sesion php en js
   localStorage.setItem("nsesion", "<?echo $nombresesion ?>");       
</script>
```

Y después en el **`js`**:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   // Sacar valor
   var nsesion = localStorage.getItem("nsesion");
   var html= '<p /><input name="name[]" id="namechild"/> <input name="nsesion[]" id="nsesionchild" value="'+nsesion+'" />'
```